# Invoking Instabug won't work on Activities without a MapView once a MapView has been added

Tags: android, instabug

It is not possible to invoke Instabug on other Activities than the one we use the MapView for once Googles MapView has been added.

Setting up Instabug looks like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
    {
        new Instabug.Builder(this, "TOKEN")
            .setInvocationEvent(IBGInvocationEvent.IBGInvocationEventShake)
            .setDefaultInvocationMode(IBGInvocationMode.IBGInvocationModeBugReporter)
            .build();
    }
```

and the MapView once acquired:

```
Instabug.addMapView(view, googleMap);
```

Invoking Instabug with the MapView works perfectly fine. But invoking it on an other Activities won't work any longer and following logs get printed:

> b: Registered Google MapView no longer exists. Skipping.
>
> Screenshot capture failed: Top most activity changed before capturing screenshot
>
> Screenshot capturing failed: Top most activity changed before capturing screenshot

Issue occurs on version 2.6.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved since version 3.0.0 .
This issue should disappear, if you just upgrade to latest version >= v3.0.5